# ZeroMQ subscription to address not working

Tags: iri-node, address

is any of you able to subscribe to ZeroMQ with address as a topic? According to the documentation this should be possible by putting the public address as a topic in socket.subscribe(). I have no problem with any other topics such as 'tx', 'sn' and so on. But when I subscribe to the address, there are no messages coming even though there is activity on the specified address. I sent few of IOTAs there and not a single transaction came from the queue. Was anyone able to subscribe to the address successfully? Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Thank you in advance, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you use the address (81digits) without the check-digits (90digits). I also fell into this pitfall.

Comment: Thank you. The address must be 81 digits. I didn't find the mistake !!!

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it out and it worked for me.

Here's the code:

```
let zmq = require('zeromq')
let sock = zmq.socket('sub')

sock.connect('tcp://zmq.devnet.iota.org:5556')
//sock.subscribe('tx')
//sock.subscribe('sn')

//My address
sock.subscribe('HELLOWORLDHELLOWORLDHELLOWORLDHELLOWORLDHELLOWORLDHELLOWORLDHELLOWORLDHELLOWORLDD')


sock.on('message', msg => {
    const data = msg.toString().split(' ') // Split to get topic & data
    switch (
    data[0] // Use index 0 to match topic
    ) {
        case 'tx':
            console.log(`I'm a TX!`, data)
            break
        case 'sn':
            console.log(`I'm a confirmed TX`, data)
            break
        case 'HELLOWORLDHELLOWORLDHELLOWORLDHELLOWORLDHELLOWORLDHELLOWORLDHELLOWORLDHELLOWORLDD':
            console.log(`I'm activity concerning that specific address`, data)
            break
    }
})
```

Maybe you forgot to include the `case '<address>':` statement in the switch statement?

Also remember that in this example the zmq-endpoint `tcp://zmq.devnet.iota.org:5556` is concerning the **devnet tangle** and not the one on the mainnet. So transactions concerning the address in my example would also have to happen on the devnet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the end I didn't make it work. I have tried devnet and even the mainnet and nothing. I wasn't using the switch there and was just logging every message coming through and not a single one was received. In the end I just stick with listening to every transaction and filtering them by receiving address.